# Make only one post request with new state after clicking on one of multiple identical components

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, state

I have a small issue and do not have a good idea how to solve it. Hope you can help

I have created a simple Starrating component. You have five stars. If you click on one of the stars the state changes and so on ... (5 stars. Rating from 1 to 5 :D ). Just basic stuff.

The main problem is based on the fact that the  Starrating component is a part of another component (AlbumList.js), which is rendered 5 times on the homepage (5 different pictures which you can rate)
(between there is another component AlbumCard.js which is holding the Starrating component  but I assume that's not important.

**Basically I have 5 components which are the same and each one of them has the Starrating Component.**

**My main goal is to click on one of the pictures, rate that and send the right state to my database.**
*The function which is sending the right rating to the database (rateAlbum), is invoked in useEffect, because only there I am able to send the new state to my database(
outside  useEffect I only have access to the new state after rendering, I guess).*

****Unfortunately if I reload the page or just make one rate the function is invoked as many times as pictures there are (5 times)****

***How do I call the function just ones if I just rated one picture or just after the onClick on the right picture with the new state ?***

**Starrating.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { FaStar } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { rateAlbum } from '../../store/actions/userAlbumRatingAction'

function Starrating({ width }) {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(null)
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null)

  const ratePicture = (rating) => {
    setRating(rating)
//  ratePicture() do not have the new state of rating
  }

    useEffect(() => {
    rateAlbum({ // function which is making the axios call
//... not imporant information just the right IDs and so on 
      rating: rating,
   
    })
  }, [rating])



  return (
    <div className='flex h-full' style={{ width: width }}>
      {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
        const ratinValue = i + 1
        return (
          <label key={ratinValue} className='flex items-center w-full'>
            <input
              className='hidden'
              type='radio'
              name='raiting'
              value={ratinValue}
              onClick={
                () => ratePicture(ratinValue)
                //  () => setRating(ratinValue)
              }
            />
            <FaStar
              className='md:m-1 w-full h-full delay-200 cursor-pointer'
              color={ratinValue <= (hover || rating) ? '#ffc107' : '#e4e5e9'}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratinValue)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
            />
          </label>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}


 export default Starrating
```

**AlbumList.js (Starrting component is a part of the AlbumCard Component)**

```
   import { connect, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchAlbum } from '../../store/actions/albumAction'

import AlbumCard from './AlbumCard'

import { setView } from '../../store/actions/uiAction'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

function AlbumList(props) {
  const newreleases = useSelector((state) => state.newReleases.NewReleases)
  const view = useSelector((state) => state.ui.view)
  const searchAlbum = useSelector((state) => state.search.albums)

  const history = useHistory()

  const onAlbumCardClick = (dataId) => {
    props.fetchAlbum(dataId)
    history.push('/home/album')
  }

  return (
    <section className='sm:flex sm:justify-between sm:flex-nowrap grid grid-cols-3'>
      {view === 'noSearch' ? (
        <>
          {newreleases.slice(0, 5).map((data) => (
            <AlbumCard
              url={data.images[0].url}
              key={data.id}
              id={data.id}
              albumname={data.name}
              onClick={() => onAlbumCardClick(data.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </>
      ) : view === 'search' ? (
        <>
          {searchAlbum.slice(0, 5).map((data, index) => (
            <AlbumCard
              url={data.images[0].url}
              key={data.id}
              id={data.id}
              albumname={data.name}
              onClick={() => onAlbumCardClick(data.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </>
      ) : null}
    </section>
  )
}

const mapDispatch = { fetchAlbum, setView }
export default connect(null, mapDispatch)(AlbumList)
```

**rateAlbum function**

```
export const rateAlbum = (data) => {
  axios.post('....', data)
}
```

**AlbumCard.js ( not important, but has the Starrting component and Albumcard.js is part of
ALbumList.js)**

```
import React from 'react'
import CardButtons from './CardButtons'
import Starrating from '../HelperComponents/Starrating'

    function AlbumCard({ url, albumname, onClick }) {
  

  return (
    <>
      <div className=' sm:m-2 sm:w-40 dark:bg-white w-24 m-1 rounded-lg shadow-md'>
        <div onClick={onClick} id='hi' className='group relative rounded-lg'>
          <img
            className='md:w-72 block w-full h-full rounded-lg'
            src={url}
            alt=''
          />

          <div className='group-hover:bg-opacity-60 group-hover:opacity-100 justify-evenly absolute top-0 flex items-center w-full h-full transition bg-black bg-opacity-0 rounded-md'>
            <CardButtons />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className=' flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-3 pb-3'>
          <p className='dark:text-black font-body whitespace-nowrap flex justify-center w-11/12 mb-2 overflow-hidden text-xs text-black'>
            {albumname}
          </p>
          <Starrating />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default AlbumCard
```

Comment: I not sure what causing this but I think the function gets called 5 times because you have 5 albums, not 5 starts so I think when clicking on one of the starts function gets called for all of the album cards. console log the state to see if it updates 5 times

Comment: Yeah that’s right ! That’s basically my problem. I have already console log it. You are right. But how can I avoid that ?

Comment: you should add the rating to the right object (using index that map function provides you ) in newreleases array because each rating is related to its own album card and send the whole updated newreleases array to the api thats how i would do it

Comment: Hmm could you explain it please a little little bit more detail. I know that you can use Index in the map function. But I do not know what the connection ist you are creating between the rating and the index.

Comment: Do you mean passing rating as a prop to Albumlist.js ?

Comment: i need access to you code besides the api call section

Comment: Which part of the code do you need exactly ? I can post that :)

Comment: Or which component do you need full ?

Comment: add the AlbumCard.js to your question to show you exacly how to do that

Comment: Ok 1 min please ! Thank you !!

Comment: also add whole AlbumList.js as well

Comment: it is done ! :)

Comment: Your id is not unique. At least in the example it's just 'hi'? Could that be the issue ?

Comment: You can see now the whole code. You can see My main main goal is of course to send the right Id and other data of the picture as well :D

Comment: @Zephyr I do not think so the id shoud not be even there. I forgot to delete them

Comment: @drag98 check the answer see if it is working

Comment: @drag98, are you fetch the rating from the database other than save? `rateAlbum` is for save it I guess

Comment: @AmirHossein give me 10 minutes. Have to look at all and implement it.

Comment: the changes that made they only updates the releases but yess thats how you should do it , each release should have a rating field and then when rating one of the releases you should update the rating field of that release and then send the updated release to the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Startrating.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { FaStar } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { rateAlbum } from '../../store/actions/userAlbumRatingAction'

function Starrating({ width, onClickStar }) {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(null)
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null)

  const ratePicture = (rating) => {
    setRating(rating)
//  ratePicture() do not have the new state of rating
  }

    useEffect(() => {
    rateAlbum({ // function which is making the axios call
//... not imporant information just the right IDs and so on 
      rating: rating,
   
    })
  }, [rating])



  return (
    <div className='flex h-full' style={{ width: width }}>
      {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => {
        const ratinValue = i + 1
        return (
          <label key={ratinValue} className='flex items-center w-full'>
            <input
              className='hidden'
              type='radio'
              name='raiting'
              value={ratinValue}
              onClick={
                () => onClickStart(ratinValue) 
                //  () => setRating(ratinValue)
              }
            />
            <FaStar
              className='md:m-1 w-full h-full delay-200 cursor-pointer'
              color={ratinValue <= (hover || rating) ? '#ffc107' : '#e4e5e9'}
              onMouseEnter={() => setHover(ratinValue)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setHover(null)}
            />
          </label>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}


 export default Starrating
```

AlbumCard,js

```
import React from 'react'
import CardButtons from './CardButtons'
import Starrating from '../HelperComponents/Starrating'

    function AlbumCard({ url, albumname, onClick, onClickStar }) {
  

  return (
    <>
      <div className=' sm:m-2 sm:w-40 dark:bg-white w-24 m-1 rounded-lg shadow-md'>
        <div onClick={onClick} id='hi' className='group relative rounded-lg'>
          <img
            className='md:w-72 block w-full h-full rounded-lg'
            src={url}
            alt=''
          />

          <div className='group-hover:bg-opacity-60 group-hover:opacity-100 justify-evenly absolute top-0 flex items-center w-full h-full transition bg-black bg-opacity-0 rounded-md'>
            <CardButtons />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className=' flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-3 pb-3'>
          <p className='dark:text-black font-body whitespace-nowrap flex justify-center w-11/12 mb-2 overflow-hidden text-xs text-black'>
            {albumname}
          </p>
          <Starrating onClickStar={onClickStar} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default AlbumCard
```

AlbumList.js

```
  import { connect, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchAlbum } from '../../store/actions/albumAction'

import AlbumCard from './AlbumCard'

import { setView } from '../../store/actions/uiAction'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

function AlbumList(props) {
  const newreleases = useSelector((state) => state.newReleases.NewReleases)
  const view = useSelector((state) => state.ui.view)
  const searchAlbum = useSelector((state) => state.search.albums)


  const [releases, setReleases] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      setReleases(newreleases)
}, [newreleases])

  const history = useHistory()
  
  const setRating = (ratingValue, index) => {
     let updatedReleases = [...releases]
     updatedReleases[index].rating = ratingValue // i'm assuming you have //rating field
     setReleases(updatedReleases)
    // then send this new releases to the api
  }

  const onAlbumCardClick = (dataId) => {
    props.fetchAlbum(dataId)
    history.push('/home/album')
  }

  return (
    <section className='sm:flex sm:justify-between sm:flex-nowrap grid grid-cols-3'>
      {view === 'noSearch' ? (
        <>
          {newreleases.slice(0, 5).map((data, index) => (
            <AlbumCard
              url={data.images[0].url}
              key={data.id}
              id={data.id}
              albumname={data.name}
              onClickStar={(ratingValue) => setRating(ratingValue, index)}
              onClick={() => onAlbumCardClick(data.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </>
      ) : view === 'search' ? (
        <>
          {searchAlbum.slice(0, 5).map((data, index) => (
            <AlbumCard
              url={data.images[0].url}
              key={data.id}
              id={data.id}
              onClickStar={(ratingValue) => setRating(ratingValue, index)}
              albumname={data.name}
              onClick={() => onAlbumCardClick(data.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </>
      ) : null}
    </section>
  )
}

const mapDispatch = { fetchAlbum, setView }
export default connect(null, mapDispatch)(AlbumList)
```

Comment: updatedReleases[index].rating = ratingValue // i'm assuming you have //rating field I do not know what do you mean with that ?

Comment: Oh know I do not have one. I have a whole reducer for the ratings in my database

Comment: But I still can not see where the starrating is getting updated ?

Comment: I just sending the rating to my database without the releases property. Just rating: req.body.rating thats it and name: req.body.name and so onn ...

Comment: well thats another situation

Comment: well you should have way of connecting the rating to the releases so you know which release is this rating for

Comment: But I got you I just changed to that and thats working fine right now !!      const setRating = (ratingValue, index) => {
    // let updatedReleases = [...releases]
    const ratingg = ratingValue // i'm assuming you have //rating field
    // setReleases(updatedReleases)
    console.log(ratingg)
    // then send this new releases to the api
  }

Comment: But the color of the starrs and not staying yellow anymore after i clicked on them . Do you know why ?

Comment: because now you don't update your rating state in the starrating.js that is why now you don't have the problem that you had before

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean thank you. I just have to find out make the colors of the starrs. Maybe passing let ratingg as a prop to Starr.js

Comment: yes that probably gonna work and your welcom

Comment: God bless you <3

Comment: do you have Paypal I would send you an european tip :)

Comment: no need my friend :)  answering questions actually helps me too

Answer (score 0):

I implement your *StarRating* component in an optimized & efficient manner.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import { rateAlbum } from "../../store/actions/userAlbumRatingAction";

function StarRating({ width }) {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);

  const ratePicture = (rating) => {
    setRating(++rating);
    console.log("clicked me");
    rateAlbum({
      rating: ++rating,
    }); // Dispatch the action to save the rating
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex h-full" style={{ width: width, display: "flex" }}>
      {[...Array(5)].map((star, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="flex items-center w-full">
          <FaStar
            className="md:m-1 w-full h-full delay-200 cursor-pointer"
            color={i < rating ? "#ffc107" : "#e4e5e9"}
            onClick={() => ratePicture(i)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default StarRating;
```

Let me know if you already implement rendering the *StarRating* component with its album's default rate to include that too in this code.

I hope this will solve all the problems related to rating.